# How to make an IntTween animation with a String?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to make an IntTween animation but not with 'int'. I have to animate how the result of an operation appears on the screen (this operation happens with letters). Therefore, I thought about using IntTween but it does not work with Strings.

```
IntTween({int? begin, int? end})
```

In that case, instead of 'int', it should be a String.

Any suggestions?

```
  class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
  );

  late final Animation<int> _animation; 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animation = IntTween(begin: 0, end: widget.result).animate( // Here is where the error is
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut));

    _animationController.forward();
  }
```

I want basically what this code does, but using `String` instead of `int`

Comment: use `class StringTween extends Tween<String> { ...` and implement [lerp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween/lerp.html) method

Comment: @pskink is there any other way to do this using an animation controller? I am a beginner and I found this lerp method really difficult.

Comment: `AnimationController`? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I added the code to the question so you can see better what I am looking for. Note that `begin: 0`  is beginning with an `int` but it should begin with a `String`. I just put 0 to match with IntTween.

Comment: what is your goal? why `String`? how will it work with `String`? for example if you have `begin: 0, end: 10` it will animate like 0,1,2, ...10, now what do you expect if you do: `begin: 'foo', end: 'lorem ipsum'`?

Comment: Ohh, I see. I am working only with the letters 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b'. The begin can be `begin: AaBb`. The end should be the `widget.result` as I put on the code above. The `result` is the result of the operation that I'm making in the code (it is basically a calculator with letters) and it changes depending on the input of the user. I didn't put how this operation works because I don't think it is important right now (I might be wrong about it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236916/discussion-between-viguinijp-and-pskink).